# Why parseInt() function does not work if we enter in prompt() function a number in quotes?

Tags: javascript

```js
var a = prompt('Enter your number: ', ''); // If we enter '22' (for example)
var b = parseInt(a, 10);
alert(b); // Our result is NaN. Why?
```

Comment: Which browser / javascript interpreter do you use?

Comment: The result is actually the number I put in.

Comment: By trying it here, using the code snippet tool, you can see it working?

Comment: seems working here

Comment: You are not really entering `'22'` (with the quotes), are you? That would explain the shown behaviour.

Comment: Also your default is `''`, so when you press enter, this will also be converted as `NaN`

Comment: I really entering '22' ! The idea to transform this string to a number. Without prompt() all is good!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to extract the digits from a string in quotes use [`match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) with a `regex`. `\d+` is "one or more digits".

```js
const a = prompt('Enter your number: ', '');
const match = a.match(/\d+/);
const b = parseInt(match, 10);
console.log(b);
```

Comment: Sorry, but :  Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'b' has already been declared
    at <anonymous>:1:1

Comment: I used `const`. Change them to `let` if you're doing something different from the example.

Comment: @Vladi, you should tick one of the answers correct when you have time.

Answer (score 2):

By literally typing `'22'` you are passing a string that can't be interpreted as a number. It's exactly the same as typing `kjlafsklja393lkadsfkj` would be `NaN`, even if there's somewhere a number in your string.